# The start and end parameter in time/window/ts/seqselect

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm new to r, and I'm having difficulties in understanding what how the start and end parameter work if provided as vectors.
Consider the code:

```
x <- c(4,6,5,4,6,2,6,7,5,5)
seqselect(x, start=6, end=10)
```

This return a vector with the integers from positions 6 to 10.
Now:

```
seqselect(x, start=c(6,1), end=c(10,5))
```

Returns values 6-10 concatenated with values from 1-5. Why is that so? What does the second value from the vector in start/end do?
Example from: [IRanges Overview](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.11/bioc/vignettes/IRanges/inst/doc/IRangesOverview.pdf) page 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misread the example code. It *actually* says:

```
seqselect(x, start=c(6,1), end=c(10,5))
# ---------------------^ 1, not 2!
```

… and of course that does exactly what the function says: it concatenates several subranges – in that case, the subranges [6, 10] and [1, 5].

In other words, `seqselect` takes a number of N start and end points and for each of the i ∈ 1…N paired start and end points, it extracts the range [start<sub>i</sub>, end<sub>i</sub>].

The `seqselect` arguments are admittedly a bit weird (I would even say the function is badly designed). It would be much more logical to specify this request as

```
seqselect(x, (6, 10), (1, 5))
```

… i.e. giving each range explicitly.

Comment: A typo indeed. Anyhow, I still can't figure out the significance of the second value.

Comment: @Szymonides See update. The function is somewhat crappy (Bioconductor libraries aren’t known for their well-designed interfaces) but still arguably self-explanatory.